# Solve Towers of Hanoi with 10 plates recursive c++

Tags: c++, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Trying to solve Towers of Hanoi, and i really can't understand why my function won't work. I have checked every c++ solution in here.

```
bool CPlayer::MoveTop(int n, int from, int to)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        m_towers.MoveDisc(to, 1);
        return true;
    }

    MoveTop(n -1 , from , 1);

    m_towers.MoveDisc(1,from);

    MoveTop(n - 1, 1, to);

}// MoveTop
```

Where 1 is the middle peg. And m_tower.MoveDisc(to,from) moves one disc from one peg to another.

And here is the first call to the function MoveTop.

```
void CPlayer::OnRun()
{
    bool ok = MoveTop(10,0,2);

}// OnRun
```

I also got a Height function that returns numbers of plates on called peg, but i don't really think I need it.

**ADDED MORE PROBLEM DESCRIBING**
All of the moves are shown in a graphic window where I can see the result of how the plates are moved from peg to peg. And now, it won't simply do what it should. When running the code the first plat moves to peg 1 (the peg in the middle) and "jumps" up and down.

These are the functions available:

The Height function:

```
int CTowers::Height(int tower)
{
    ASSERT( torn>=0 && torn<3 );

    return m_height[torn];
}
```

Returns Height on specific tower.

```
int CTowers::TopSize(int tower)
{

        int h = Height(tower);
        if (h==0)
            return 1000;
        else return DiscSize(torn, h-1);
}
```

Returns the size of top on peg.

```
int CTowers::DiscSize(int tower, int place)
{
    ASSERT( place < Height(torn) );

    return m_pinne[tower][place];
}
```

Returns specified dicssize.

```
bool CTowers::MoveDisc(int to, int from)
{
  if (m_abort)
      return false;   //    

  m_pView->DrawAnimation( from, to );

  if (TopSize(from)>=TopSize(to))
        return false;
  m_numMoves++;
  int ds = Pop(from);
  Push(to, ds );
  m_pView->Invalidate();
  return true;
}
```

Moves a disc from one peg to another.

Comment: Please describe in what way your function does not work.

Comment: You should definitely call `m_towers.MoveDisc(to, 1);` outside the recursive function, because you're "demolishing" those towers before all subsequent calls (due to the recursive nature of the function). BTW, this function assumes that `from != 1` and `to != 1`.

Comment: @barakmanos Could you please develop your thoughts? Should I only have `m_towers.MoveDisc(1,from);` inside the function? And I dont really get the assumstions your talked about.

Comment: What I meant is that you should call `m_towers.MoveDisc(2, 1)` only after function `MoveTop` has returned `ok = true`. What I meant with the assumption is that if you call `MoveTop(10,0,1)`, for example, it will probably not work as planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old school :) divide & conquer problem.

Try looking at this code:

```
void hanoi(int diskSize, int source, int dest, int spare)
{
  //This is our standard termination case. We get to here when we are operating on the 
  //smallest possible disk.
  if(diskSize == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Move disk " << diskSize << " from peg " << source << " to peg " << dest << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //Move all disks smaller than this one over to the spare.
        //So if diskSize is 5, we move 4 disks to the spare. This leaves us with 1 disk
        //on the source peg.
        //Note the placement of the params.
        //We are now using the dest peg as the spare peg. This causes each recursion to ping-pong
        //the spare and dest pegs.
        hanoi(diskSize - 1, source, spare, dest);

        //Move the remaining disk to the destination peg.
        std::cout << "Move disk "  << diskSize << " from peg " << source << " to peg " << dest << endl;

        //Move the disks we just moved to the spare back over to the dest peg.
        hanoi(diskSize - 1, spare, dest, source);
    }
}
```

The idea of having 3 arguments (source, dest, spare) is to be able to know at each time which peg is the spare one so that you can use it for putting disks on it.

As stated in the comments, the recursion ping-pongs between the spare and the dest.

Your code cannot respect the rule where **you cannot put a larger disk on top of a smaller disk** (see **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi)**). So you need a variable to keep **the target peg which is not always 1** like in your code.

That's why you need 3 arguments.

Cheers!

Comment: This is exactly how every version is looking like, as I said, I have look at almost every lookalike of your code at this site, but some how it doesn't work with my code.

Comment: Well the problem is that this is how the function has to look like. Are you somehow constrained to use only 3 parameters in the function? What does it mean that it does not work. Maybe the problem is the visualization tool.

Comment: But surely there got to be a another way of solving the problem too, this task was given as a lab at my school. But Thanks for your time, but i can't mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @user3374547 Can you post additional information? We cannot figure out what's not working?

Comment: Done. Got it to work with your posted solution, but changed the parameters of the function which I don't think is legit for this task.

Comment: I don't get it, but i don't think we should mess around anywhere but inside the MoveTop function and OnRun.

Comment: See my new comments in the post.

Comment: Thanks for your time, you did post a correct answer so I will mark your answer as the correct one.